# Show application on multiple screens

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have an Application which should be shown on multiple screens **simultaneously**. With the main screen is not a problem, but it does not work for the second screen

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, just retrieve frame of the second screen and show window in main screen but using the frame of the second screen

```
NSRect secScreenRect = [secondScreen frame];

myWindow = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:secScreenRect
                                                 styleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask
                                                   backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
                                                     defer:NO
                                                    screen:[NSScreen mainScreen]];
...
```

Comment: Be careful with the mainScreen message. It doesn't mean what most people assume. That message returns the screen with the current keyboard focus, not the one with the menu bar. If you want the screen with the menu bar use [[NSScreen screens] objectAtIndex:0]